# Replacement for httplogger for Grails >2.5

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I used the Grails httplogger plugin for years and found it very useful for debugging my application.

It does not work with Grails 2.5.6 and later. Is there a replacement? Is there another way to log HTTP requests/responses... easily!?

Comment: Good time to upgrade the plugin to grails3 ur self and contribute back to community. Shoudnt be that hard

Comment: Considering that I spent an entire day upgrading my app to Grails 2.5.6 from Grails 2.3.7, I do not feel motivated to take your suggestion. I'm guessing it would take me quite some time and wouldn't be "not that hard". For me at least. YMMV

Comment: Depends on application, but sooner or later you have to upgrade, grails 2.x is no longer going to get any new releases

Comment: It's not true that sooner or later I'll have to upgrade. I may not be on the project or the project may die before an upgrade is "necessary". So I cannot use that argument alone as reason to invest time in an HttpLogger update. My current cost/benefit analysis suggests it is not a good time to upgrade the plugin myself. I'm all for giving back to the community and do. Not in this case, sorry, but thanks for the reminder that this is a real possibility.